# Assigning colours to polygons for a large number of categories on a map in R

Tags: r, plot, mapping, categorical-data

I am attempting to plot a map of different vegetation types which I have called grass. The categories are listed under grass@data$LEGEND. There are 72 in total. I do not care what the colours are but there must be a different colour for each vegetation type and some of the vegetation types appear i more than one polygon.

```
poly<-readOGR(".","vegmap2006_geo")
out <- crop(poly, extent(20, 35,-26, -32))
grass<-poly[poly@data$BIOME%in%"Grassland Biome",]

colours<-terrain.colors(72)
plot(grass,col=colours[grass$LEGEND],border=NA)
```

Nothing happens when I plot and I have no idea why. I can plot the map with the following code

```
plot(grass,col=grass$LEGEND, border=NA)
```

however the R colour palette does not contain enough colours for each vegetation type to be coloured differently

Comment: What's in `grass$LEGEND` column? We need a reproducible example to be of help...

Comment: Maybe this could work: `plot(grass,col=colours[as.numeric(factor(grass$LEGEND))],border=NA)`

Comment: Hi grass$LEGEND is a list of all the vegetation types associated with each polygon (i.e.. grass@data$LEGEND). I have just tried plotting your suggestion and although I'm not entirely sure what the code does it has now produced a plot with colours

Comment: Thanks I think this seems to have worked

Comment: Quick explanation: I just turned the strings in LEGEND into factors that basically maps unique string values with integer numbers in {1..n}, then I used this numbers as indexes of colours...

Answer (score 0):

Help for colors. For getting the list of `colors` available in R, type

```
 colors()  # All colors
```

For getting specific shades of some color, let's say `red`or `blue` or `green` or `orange` type

```
 colors()[grep("red",colors())]           # Shades of red
 colors()[grep("blue",colors())]          # Shades of blue
 colors()[grep("green",colors())]         # Shades of green
 colors()[grep("orange",colors())]        # Shades of orange
```